# Payment with credit card execution

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've created a payment with credit card as shown at: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK#create-payment

Do i need `payer_id` to execute the payment?

Comment: you need `payer_id`,  `Only for Payment with payment_method as "paypal"`. I understand the doc this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. It all depends on the payment method used... For example paypal id, credit card object, credit card token (from paypal vault) all are methods that require you to post different information to paypal

Go to this page @ https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/tree/master/samples/payment

Look at the samples files 
"create_with_credit_card_token.rb",
 "create_with_credit_card.rb"
 "create_with_paypal.rb"
 There you should be able to find the information you need